# Is it possible to emplace a non copyable, non moveable into a std::variant

Tags: c++, c++20, std-variant

See

https://godbolt.org/z/Pv8xfeE17

fails

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct T {
    int _x;
    T(int x) : _x(x) { std::cout << "constructed" << std::endl; }
    #if 0
        T(const T& t) : _x(t._x) { std::cout << "copied" << std::endl; }
        T( T&& t) : _x(t._x) { std::cout << "moved" << std::endl; }
    #else
        T(const T& t) = delete;
        T(T&& t) = delete;
    #endif

};


T make_t(){
    return T(1);
}

int main() {

    std::variant<std::monostate,T> v;
    v.emplace<T>(make_t());
}
```

passes

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct T {
    int _x;
    T(int x) : _x(x) { std::cout << "constructed" << std::endl; }
    #if 1
        T(const T& t) : _x(t._x) { std::cout << "copied" << std::endl; }
        T(const T&& t) : _x(t._x) { std::cout << "moved" << std::endl; }
    #else
        T(const T& t) = delete;
        T(const T&& t) = delete;
    #endif

};


T make_t(){
    return T(1);
}

int main() {

    std::variant<std::monostate,T> v;
    v.emplace<T>(make_t());
}
```

Comment: You create two copies (though the first should be elided): First  your `make_t` function creates an instance and then returns a copy. Then the returned copy will be used to copy-construct the `T` object inside the variant. Doing e.g. `v.emplace<T>(1)` should work fine.

Comment: I want copy+move ellision to emplace directly into the variant. Is this possible?

Comment: `v.emplace<T>(make_t())` is an explicit invoke of the copy-constructor. It can't be elided.

Comment: On a different note, `const T&&` almost *never* makes sense. A "move" can't be done from a constant object.

Comment: Yeah. My bad! I fixed that for non-const move constructor. But the issue is the same.

Comment: The issue is that we have a non-moveable + non-copyable object returned from a function and we need to put it in a variant.

Comment: What you call your "issue" is actually a solution to *another* problem that you need to solve. What is that original problem? Why do you need a variant? Why do you need to use non-copyable and non-movable objects?

Comment: In summary we have a class that encapsulates a lazy initialized value. A lambda is stored in the class and the first time the object is dereferenced ( like a pointer ) the lambda is invoked and called and the value is stored in the variant. The variant is std::variant<std::monostate, T, std::exceptionptr>. This was all working fine till a colleague tried to generate a non copyable / non movable in the factory function.

Comment: A full example with our lazy class is here. https://godbolt.org/z/83Tx1eacz if it helps to understand the context.

Comment: Putting exception and `std::monostate` in `std::variant` seems a bit inefficient in terms of type count. You either have a value or an exception, hence monostate would be unnecessary. Other than that you can just: `std::variant<T, T1, T2> var {std::in_place_type_t<T>, args...};` and `var.emplace<T>(args...);`. you need to use `args` directly with `var`, instead of `make_t(args...)`. The `make_t` case needs `T` to be at-least movable. More over, you may consider `std::expected` for error handling, rather than exception based coding;  The monadic interface is interesting.

Comment: If you see the full example ( comment above ) you will understand

Comment: The full example just confirms every single point in my previous post. `std::expected` is what you really need,  instead of `std::variant`. And you should get a variadic template constructor for your class to forward everything to real data.

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm sorry but this is not ture. The case is the same for std::expected or std::variant or std::optional. You can't emplace an already constructed non-copyable / non-moveable object into them. you can't elide the move or the copy. It would be possible but the API for these classes don't allow it.

Comment: The class needs to provide at least one publicly accessible constructor - in order to be used as a none-static data memeber in any other class. That means a single `make_t` won't work with immobile object as a member of any other class. You need a constructor with same set of arguments as `make_t`.

Comment: Again. You are wrong. Sorry. The solution to the problem was linked in the duplicate. The issue is now closed. Wrapping the make_t in the *initializer* wrapper allows noncopyable and nonmovable objects to be emplaced into std::variant.

Answer (score 0):

You need `v.emplace<T>(1);`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YMqjv3rq4)

Comment: Sorry this doesn't meet the requirements. There needs to be a factory function that generates the object. I am aware that you can emplace with the constructor arguments. Sorry.